# How do I get past the first turret in Deus Ex Human Revolution?

Tags: achievements, deus-ex-human-revolution

I'm trying to get past it without it going hostile so I can get the Foxiest of the Hounds achievement, but I can't get to the door across the hallway (not the one with the concussion mine next to it) without it spotting me.

I've taken the large crate and tossed it down the hallway to block the turrets view of me, but even with a tiny little gap between the crates the turret spots me.

Is the only way to use my first and only Praxis point for a strength augmentation, and then physically move the turret out of the way?

Comment: Wait... you can move turrets with the strength upgrade? I'll have to remember that...

Comment: Not only can you move them, you can hurl them into sewer water for funsies on occasion.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There should be a vent that leads to the other end of the hallway behind the turret (where the advanced hacking tutorial is made available).  There's also a number of cardboard boxes in the vicinity.  Just grab some and stack them up in front of the turret so it cannot see into the hallway.  The turret won't see you as long as you stay behind the crates.

After you obstruct its view, you could then return to the other end of the hallway and make your way into the room.

Comment: +1. What I did to make this easier was to take two long cardboard boxes and drop them so that the far end was over the turret; this resulted in two vertical cardboard boxes. I then put one in front of the left half of the turret and one in front of the right half, and found that the turret couldn't see me at all.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. I was trying to throw a crate in the middle of the hallway on the other end thinking I could hide behind it. I didn't know I could get that close to the turret without it seeing me.

Comment: Ah, *that* is what I should have done! ;)

Comment: @Brandon: Like all other things in the game you need to hide from, they have lines of sight that only react if they see you.  Stuff you carry that crosses this won't alert them (lasers don't count).  You won't see it at first until you get the right augments that shows them on the radar.  Just know that turrets and cameras have a very narrow view so it should be pretty safe get close to them (as long as you don't step in front of it).  For the turret, just imagine a rectangle in front of it the width of the turret as the danger zone.

Comment: Damn I tried quite a few things to get this to work, but thought i probably had to have Stealth enabled or something to not set it off, so I gave up... Will have to remember this if I try a second playthrough

Answer (score 2):

> Is the only way to use my first and only Praxis point for a strength augmentation, and then physically move the turret out of the way?

No, aside from Jeff's method or using your Praxis Kit on the Move/Throw Heavy Objects augmentation - if you picked up a [Frag Grenade] along the way (in a storage room). You move through the vent taking you behind the turret and throw a grenade at the turret.  It will destroy it without triggering any alarms.

Took me ages to figure out a stealthy option to this situation also.